# net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException on startTrackedFlow returnValue

Tags: kotlin, corda

```
val signedTx = rpc.startTrackedFlow(
                    ::CreateDeviceFlow,
                    deviceState,
                    DeviceContract.Commands.Create())
                    .returnValue.getOrThrow()
```

After an upgrade to 4.3 I ran into this issue currently, the call returnValue.getOrThrow throws a Kotlin NPE. The flow is not called at all.

Everything starting up without problems, Contracts are validated as well.

Any reasons I am missing why an NPE can be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, changed the Notary's particulars, wasn't found did not cater for it, just used !! instead of ?: and throwing a proper exception.